# AttributeError in counting negative words from input string

Tags: python

This is my code for counting negative words from an input string:

```py
for word in neg_words:
    if word!=neg_words[-1]:
        print('\'{0},\''.format(word),end=' ')
    else:
        print('and \'{0}.\''.format(word))
    print()

    my_string = input("Type here without quotes what the customer said: ")
    split_up_my_string = my_string.split()
    negative = 0

    for i in split_up_my_string:
        if word in i.my_string.split():
            negative += 1
    print()
    print("This consumer mentioned negative keywords a total of " + int(negative) + " times.")
```

What am I missing...

Here's the error I am getting:

```
Error message:
  if word in i.my_string.split():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'my_string'
```

Comment: You have `split_up_my_string=my_string.split()`, so `split_up_my_string` is a list of strings. Then you have `for i in split_up_my_string:`, so `i` is now a string from that list, one at a time. Then finally, you go `if word in i.my_string.split():` - a string does not have a `.my_string` attribute, so neither does `i`.

Answer (score 1):

The mistakes are here:

```
 for i in split_up_my_string:
     if word in i.my_string.split():
         negative += 1
```

Change the code like this:

```
 if word in split_up_my_string:
     negative += 1
```

But I think your algoritm and code flow is not right, refactoring is needed.